# JSON convert dictionary to a list of key value pairs

Tags: json

I have a Dictionary <string, string>

If I Json.Encode this I get `{"Apple":"Apples","Orange":"Oranges"}`

How I can get this to:-

```
[{ value: "Apples", key: "Apple" }, { value: "Oranges", key: "Orange"}]
```

Preferably using Newtonsoft.Json or jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert it to a list of key value pairs before passing to the JSON serializer:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>(dictionary));
```

Comment: Thank you

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>(dictionary)); 

did the trick

Comment: @Gordon Hickley, great, thanks for confirming which worked.  I'll edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @Samuel, do you know the reason for the different behaviours? Returning an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> or IDictionary<string, int> results in flattening as reported by Gorden but change type to IList<KeyValuePair<string, int>> and all is well...

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate my comment, changing the data type from an IEnumerable> (or IDictionary) to a IList> will also cause the serialization to work "correctly" a.k.a. serialize the data as a JavaScript array. In my current situation, my JavaScript is isolated in a separate .js file where Razor can't follow so using JsonConvert.SerializeObject wasn't an option.

Definitely an odd bit of functionality here. It would be great if anyone has some insight as to why JSON serialization reacts the way by default; bug or intentional?