# JSON object deserialize to c# object - OpenTSDB

Tags: c#, json, opentsdb

I am dealing with JSON for the first time and getting data from OpenTSDB. I've created a c# class to deserialize the JSON to but I am getting the error *'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array'* as described below.

**My c# code to get JSON:**

```
 var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:4242/api/query?start=2013/08/21-12:00:00&end=2013/08/22-12:00:00&m=sum:tcollector.collector.lines_sent&o=&yrange=%5B0:%5D&wxh=924x773");
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        string text;
        try
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            uxResponse.Text = text;

            OpenTSDBResponse myObject = (OpenTSDBResponse)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text, typeof(OpenTSDBResponse));

            var variable = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);

            //var tester = myObject;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            uxResponse.Text = GetFullExceptionMessage(ex);
        }
```

**The JSON I am receiving from the above code (i.e. the 'text' variable):**

```
[{
"metric":"tcollector.collector.lines_sent",
"tags":
    {
    "host":"ubuntu1"
    },
"aggregateTags":["collector"],
"dps":
    {
    "1377050434":1271779.0,
    "1377050494":1272073.0,
    "1377050554":1272502.0,
    "1377050614":1273632.0,
    "1377050674":1273867.0
    }
}]
```

**My c# classes**

```
 internal class OpenTSDBResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("metric")]
        public string Metric { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tags")]
        public Tags Tags { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("aggregateTags")]
        public string[] AggregateTags { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dps")]
        public List<TimeValue> TimeValues { get; set; }
    }

internal class Tags
{

    [JsonProperty("host")]
    public string Host { get; set; }
}

internal class TimeValue
{
    [JsonProperty("Time")]
    public double Time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

**The error when deserializing object:**

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 
>   'MyNamespace.OpenTSDBResponse'     because the type requires a JSON
>   object (e.g.  {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.To fix this
>   error either change the JSON to a  JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   or change the deserialized type to an array or a type  that implements
>   a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
>   be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
>   added to the type to force  it to deserialize from a JSON array.Path
>   '', line 1, position 1.

**Additional Information**

I used the codeproject deserialize JSON project to create my basic classes, but it created a new c# property for each '"1377050434":1271779.0,' so I updated to use my TimeValue class. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C

**Question:**

How do I get this into an appropriate c# class structure?

**Additional Information in response to users comments below:**

- **bjaminn's comment:** 
  I believe the JSON you are receiving is an array. The exception is trying to say you are converting an object[] to OpenTSDBResponse when you really want OpenTSDBResponse[]. Another way to debug this would be to look at the variable variable and see what type it is in the debugger. Of course the line that throws the exception would need to be commented out.

  **Outcome:** I modified the deserialize like this

  OpenTSDBResponse[] myObject = (OpenTSDBResponse[])Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text, typeof(OpenTSDBResponse[]));

  but received the following error when I ran it:

  > Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNamespace.OpenTSDBResponseJsonTypes.TimeValue]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.Path '[0].dps.1377050434', line 1, position 121.

**Additional Notes on working solution for other new to JSON**
I have added another property to my class for the Dictionary as it's really "unix-time-stamp-data","Value". This allows me to work in c# with datetime/values. There may be a better way for casting but this works an doesn't cause any noticeable performance issues for my scenario.

```
    [JsonProperty("dps")]
    public Dictionary<string, double> TimeValues { get; set; }

    public List<TimeValue> DataPoints
    {
        get
        {
            List<TimeValue> times = new List<TimeValue>();
            DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            foreach (var item in TimeValues)
            {
                times.Add(new TimeValue
                {
                    Time = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(double.Parse(item.Key)).ToLocalTime(),
                    Value = item.Value
                });
            }

            return times;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the JSON you are receiving is an array.  The exception is trying to say you are converting an *object[]* to *OpenTSDBResponse* when you really want *OpenTSDBResponse[]*.

Another way to debug this would be to look at the variable *variable* and see what type it is in the debugger.  Of course the line that throws the exception would need to be commented out.

**Tackling new error**
It looks like DPS is not a proper JSON array.  You could parse it to a dictionary since it looks like the keys will be different in each JSON call.

[JSON convert dictionary to a list of key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856357/json-convert-dictionary)

New class:

```
    internal class OpenTSDBResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("metric")]
        public string Metric { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tags")]
        public Tags Tags { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("aggregateTags")]
        public string[] AggregateTags { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dps")]
        public Dictionary<string,double> TimeValues { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my question after I tried your suggestion. Different error, did I modify the code as you expected? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the updated example, the dictionary<string,double> sorted this out for me.

Comment: Can I cast the Dictionary<string,double> to be Dictionary<DateTime,double> as the strings are unix dates?

Comment: @John I would imagine that possible with some conversion.  I have not dug deeply into the library.  A few weeks back I had issues similar to your original issues so I thought I would save you the troubles I had.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can such so modify your Json Data and your C# Code,for example
    [{
    "metric":"tcollector.collector.lines_sent",
    "tags":
    {
    "host":"ubuntu1"
    },
    "aggregateTags":["collector"],
    "dps":
    [
    {"Time":"1377050434","Value":1271779.0},
    {"Time":"1377050554","Value":1272502.0}        
    ]
    }]
c# Code:        
You provide the data is an Array,so when you deserialize the string,you must such so use generic format of deserializeobject

    object obj=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OpenTSDBResponse>>(json.ToString());
```

Comment: I don't think I can modify the JSON - I believe it comes from OpenTSDB in a standard format.